# Find the registry key that has a value of a certain name in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, registry

I know I have a registry entry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/CLASSES that has a certain value.  However, I don't know the Key.  (This is a GUID that I am trying to look up.)  The following code works to get to this value, but it's slow and seems inelegant.  Is there a better way of doing it?

```
$key = Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes" -Recurse | Get-ItemProperty -Name "FooBar" -ErrorAction @{}
$codeGuid = $key.PsChildName
```

Answer (score 3):

The recurse is what kills you. To lighten the burden of recursively searching Classes, you can manually specify a Depth. If you KNOW how many steps your key is into the Registry Hierarchy, you can cut the speed significantly. For example:

```
$Timer = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch

######NORMAL#######
#Completes in 70.2157527 Seconds on my system
$Timer.Start()
    Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes" -Recurse | Get-ItemProperty -Name "AlwaysShowExt" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
$Timer.Stop()
$Timer.Elapsed
$Timer.Reset()

######DEPTH 1######
#Completes in 12.7461096 Seconds on my system
$Timer.Start()
    Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes" -Recurse -Depth 1 | Get-ItemProperty -Name "AlwaysShowExt" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
$Timer.Stop()
$Timer.Elapsed
$Timer.Reset()

######DEPTH 2######
#Completes in 33.9162044 Seconds on my system
$Timer.Start()
    Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes" -Recurse -Depth 2 | Get-ItemProperty -Name "AlwaysShowExt" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
$Timer.Stop()
$Timer.Elapsed
$Timer.Reset()
```

Your best results are going to be with a Depth of 1, but Depths of 2 or 3 will still be faster than not specifying.

Comment: I am at a depth of 2; so this is better than before.  But is there a way to stop the search once the first is found?  That may improve things even better.

Comment: @afeygin There's probably a way to do it but I'm not aware of it. I'll let you if I find a way. Also, the Depth param only works after Powershell v5. If you need an alternative you can do something like: Get-ChildItem HKLM:\Software\Classes\\*\\*\\*

Comment: I found that I could locate the key a lot faster by looking in "HKLM:\Software\Classes\Installer\Features" instead of just "HKLM:\Software\Classes".